# Using JUnit with exceptions

Tags: eclipse, junit

I would like to test for an `IllegalArgumentException` in a `while(true)` statement of a method. I've tried three ways that are presented on many sites and still don't get it enough to figure out why it's not working. Here is my method under test:

```java
public double computeBid(double myHours){
        double dblBogusValue=0;
        double dblNewHours=0;
        double dblMyBid=0;
        double dblMyHours=myHours;

        if(myHours >dblBogusValue){
            dblMyHours=myHours*25; 
            return dblMyHours;
        }
        else{
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print(this.getStrCompanyName()+" Enter the Hours for the bid:");

            while(true){
                String strEntered = keyboard.next();
                try{
                    dblNewHours=Double.parseDouble(strEntered);

                    if((dblNewHours >0) && (dblNewHours<=120)){ 
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Enter a Number greater than zero.");
                    }
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            //      System.out.println("Enter a Value in number format from 0 to 120." + e);
                }
            }
        }
        dblMyBid=dblNewHours* 25.00;
        return dblMyBid;
    }
```

And here is the test *(I left the comments in so you could see my thought process and other attempts)*

```java
    @Rule public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test//(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class) //this doen't work as presented.
//  @Test
    public void testAnotherHandyManFailComputeBid() {
        thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
        HandyMan handy = new HandyMan();
        System.out.println("Enter a zero or negitive number to cause" +
                 " a IllegalArgumentException.");//Inform testing agent of required action
        handy.computeBid(-1);// force method called to enter test condition
        //(generate exception)
    //provide condition to exit method
        assertEquals(25,handy.computeBid(1),.1);
    }
```

Comment: It's a textbook example of why methods should only do one thing: if you separated keyboard input from calculating logic testing would be trivial.

Comment: ok, I like that and can easily make it happen. Bryon

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to test two things: does your method return a double value and does your method log (not throw) an IllegalArgumentException? Additionally you want to read user input from System.in which you need to provide in your test.

You can use [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/#StandardErrorStreamLog) to interact with System.in und System.out in JUnit.

```
@Rule
public final TextFromStandardInputStream input = emptyStandardInputStream();

@Rule
public final StandardOutputStreamLog output = new StandardOutputStreamLog();

@Test
public void testAnotherHandyManFailComputeBid() {
    input.provideText("12345");

    HandyMan handy = new HandyMan();
    assertEquals(yourExpectedResult, handy.computeBid(-1));

    assertTrue(output.getLog().contains("IllegalArgumentException"));
}
```

If your method should throw an IllegalArgumentException to the invoker then you should simply remove the try-catch.

Comment: Further research show that the reason junit is not able to capture the thown exception is due to the catch inside the method under test. I have found the answer I was looking for and wanted to thank everyone that viewed the question. Thanks! Bryon

Comment: I will read up on the System Rules you have provided. In my original read of JUnit @Test (expected...) I thought ANY exception was captured. It turns out that because I caught the exception, it isn't registered as thrown by JUnit. I do like keeping the loop going, forcing a positive response from the user. I will read the System Rules and learn how to test this. I can use this method later if its testable. Thanks.